# What is the equivalent of this syntax in Java?

Tags: java, translate

Just a quick question about how to convert a certain line of code between c++ and Java. I've been learning about Neural Networks and I've been starting to write my own in the language I have the most experience with, Java. It's been pretty straightforward to translate the code from C++ to Java so far, however there's one little issue I've ran into. I'm puzzled by how to translate this specific line of code into a Java equivalent, and I can't find anything specific to this issue through searching.

The original code is:

```
Struct SNeuron {
   //the number of inputs into the neuron

   int m_NumInputs;
   //the weights for each input
   vector<double> m_vecWeight;
   //ctor
   SNeuron(int NumInputs);
};
```

and my code is:

```
public class SNeuron {

public int m_NumInputs; // the number of inputs into the neuron
public ArrayList<Double> m_vecWeight = new ArrayList<Double>(); // the weights for each input
// ctor
```

My question is, how do I convert:

```
SNeuron(int NumInputs);
```

into its Java equivalent? From what i've read, Structs don't seem to be a feature Java uses, so i'm just struggling a bit to understand what exactly that line of code actually does in the context it's used.

Comment: How is that function called? It's called the same in Java. :)

Comment: It's a constructor. I was under the impression they use the same syntax in Java.

Comment: The only difference between classes and structs is the default access protection levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SNeuron 
{

// the number of inputs into the neuron

public int m_NumInputs;

// the weights for each input

public List<Double> m_vecWeight = new ArrayList<Double>();

// ctor
SNeuron(int NumInputs) {
   m_NumInputs = NumInputs;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! I had a feeling I had to give it a body, but it didn't feel right leaving the body empty. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, if u haven't got any questions please mark answer as a solved.

Answer (score 1):

Given the comments in code, I'm pretty sure the equivalent is:

```
public class SNeuron {
    public final double[] weights;

    public SNeuron(int numInputs) {
        weights = new double[numInputs];
    }
}
```

You don't really want to use a `List<Double>`, it will be much slower and take much more memory - each double in such a list becomes a full-fledged object with all associated overheads.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `SNeuron(int NumInputs);` is the declaration of a constructor taking an `int`, and this is contained within the class declaration.

You don't do that in Java - effectively all constructors, and all functions for that matter, are inlined in the class declaration. In other words

```
SNeuron(int NumInputs); // within the class declaration
SNeuron::SNeuron(int NumInputs) : m_NumInputs(NumInputs){} // In a translation unit
```

maps to

```
SNeuron(int NumInputs) {
   m_NumInputs = NumInputs;
}
```

but note that using `m_` for Java *fields* is idiosyncratic.

Comment: @Angew: It means I need a coffee. Do you want one too?

Comment: No, thanks :-) I'm probably the only such programmer on the planet, but I don't drink coffee.